# Can a chain link node listen to ethereum smart contracts events?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, events, oracles, chainlink

Can a chain link node listen to ethereum smart contracts events? Let’s say I want to provide data to a node from a smart contract. Can a I link a chain link node and use a smart contract as an oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In fact that’s how the Chainlink nodes operate.

When calling `buildChainlinkRequest` and `sendChainlinkRequestTo` In the [any API call feature](https://docs.chain.link/docs/request-and-receive-data) you are actually emitting events that chainlink nodes look for.

You can modify this to have a node looo for your specific event, but you need to use a node that uses an `ethLog` initiator instead of `runLog`. Check out the [initiators](https://docs.chain.link/docs/initiators) documentation.

Comment: What listens for the ethereum smart contract events? Is it a chain link smart contract or a single chain link node?

Comment: Smart contracts can’t “listen” to events, only an off-chain system can. So it’s the chainlink node that listens.